# Unity C#, How to call a function from another script to start animation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine; using System.Collections;

public class ClickToMoveScript : MonoBehaviour  
{
    public string Chopping = "Chopping";

    public void PlayWoodCuttingAnim()   
    {       
        //Play Woodcutting Animation        
        gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>().CrossFade (Chopping);  
    }     
}
```

Heres my other Script

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System.Collections;

public class WoodCuttingScript: MonoBehaviour  
{
    ClickToMoveScript ClickToMove;

    void Start()
    {
        ClickToMove.PlayWoodCuttingAnim();  
    }  
}
```

[image: Unity Debugger]

I have already added the animation inside the animation component.

The other thing i found out is that if i call the PlayWoodCuttingAnim() function inside ClickToMove script it works fine but in the other script it dosent work.

The error console > NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you assign ClickToMove from inspector?

Comment: standard way of doing this in Unity is to 1. make your ClickToMove variable public, 2. select your object with WoodCuttingScript in hierarchy in Unity, drop the object with ClickToMoveScript in the ClickToMove slot in inspector. (keep WoodCuttingScript selected all the time, do not select ClickToMoveScript)

Comment: is `ClickToMoveScript` attached to another gameObject?

Comment: I not work with Unity3d some time ago but it looks just a object reference problem. Try to do `ClickToMove = new ClickToMoveScript();` before `ClickToMove.PlayWoodCuttingAnim();` or attach ClickToMoveScript to the gameObject and do `gameObject.GetComponent<ClickToMoveScript>().PlayWoodCuttingAnim();` instead  `ClickToMove.PlayWoodCuttingAnim();`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, there are few common methods to do so.

Like calling method from another script you will need to get attached (to gameObject) script instance instead of simple script instance.

You can do it by,

```
void Start()
{
    ClickToMove = FindObjectOfType<ClickToMoveScript>();
    ClickToMove.PlayWoodCuttingAnim();  
}
```

Comment: 2nd is delegate, if you want to play with delegates, then let me know

Comment: That is only valid if you have only one ClickToMoveScript.

Comment: Yups. if you have multiple then `ClickToMoveScript[] ClickToMoveArray  = FindObjectsOfType<ClickToMoveScript>();` then call `foreach(ClickToMoveScript c in ClickToMoveArray ) c.PlayWoodCuttingAnim();  `

Comment: Thanks for the code@HamzaHasan this works like a charm :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `.GetComponent<YourScriptName>.YourFunction()`.

Your function will (I believe) have to be public in order to use in another script :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `GetComponent` to get instance of another script.

```
    ClickToMove= gameObject.GetComponent("ClickToMoveScript") as ClickToMoveScript;
    ClickToMove.PlayWoodCuttingAnim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i use:

```
FindObjectOfType<Sliding_Door>().Open_Door(1);
```

You can also use:

```
Sliding_Door door = FindObjectOfType<Sliding_Door>();
door.Open_Door(1);
```

Here is your version

```
FindObjectOfType<ClickToMoveScript>().PlayWoodCuttingAnim();
```

or

```
ClickToMoveScript init = FindObjectOfType<ClickToMoveScript>();
init.PlayWoodCuttingAnim();
```

Answer (score -3):

You need to create a new istance of clicktomove like `ClickToMoveScript ClickToMove = new ClickToMoveScript();`

Comment: This is not true, you cannot instatiate MonoBehaviour.